# jquery ajax:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I use jquery ajax to do a cross-domain request job:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'http://someurl',
    dataType : "jsonp",
    jsonp: 'callback',
    success: function (data) {

    }
})
```

but there is occur a error:`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

my request json data is just like:

```
{
    "status": "ok", 
    "info": {
        "book_count": 54, 
        "title": "recommended"
    }, 
    "books": [
        {
            "iap_price": "", 
            "book_category": "yippee_education", 
            "book_category_desc": "\u4e50\u8c5a\u65e9\u6559", 
        }
    ]
}
```

So what's wrong with my code?How can I fixed this problem?

Comment: you can't access the cross domain data with ajax, but you can do a simple trick to call a php file with ajax and fetch the result in your php file with CURL..

Comment: Which line are you getting this issue?

Comment: @PraveenKumar: the second line `"status": "ok"`

Answer (score 0):

If this JSON is validated, I get an error:

```
{
    "status": "ok", 
    "info": {
        "book_count": 54, 
        "title": "recommended"
    }, 
    "books": [
        {
            "iap_price": "", 
            "book_category": "yippee_education", 
            "book_category_desc": "\u4e50\u8c5a\u65e9\u6559", 
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Error:

```
Parse error on line 11:
...                   }    ]}
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING'
```

Don't give a comma `,` at the end of `"book_category_desc": "\u4e50\u8c5a\u65e9\u6559",`. That should solve.

Comment: In fact my data very long, so I just show part of it, so it's my mistak to leave a comma here...But I sill want validate it, how can I do that?

Comment: You can use the PHP's (if you are using PHP) function, [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to output valid JSON. :)